# How to say "One day we will meet"?

Tags: translation

Could you help me to translate the phrase "One day we will meet" or "Some day we will meet". My guess is "一旦我们相遇". Pls correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on the context behind "One day we will meet"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can try [Google Translate](https://translate.google.ca/#en/zh-CN/one%20day%20we%20will%20meet).

When you input "One day we will meet"  the result from Google Translate will be:  "有一天我們會見"

It is now close to 100% correct. If you are learning Chinese, you should have learned most English verbs are converted to two characters compound words in Chinese. "Meet" translate to "見" seem out of place and it is the first thing to check.

To refine the sentence,  input "Meet" and you will see a list of Chinese words

1.满足: meet, satisfy, fulfill, content, fill, suffice

2.见: see, refer, meet, catch sight of, be exposed to

3.会面: meet, get together, hold a meeting

4.见面: meet, see

5.迎接: meet, greet, welcome, receive, salute

6.会见: meet, pay a visit

7.遇见: meet, occur, forgather, rencounter

8.碰面: meet

9.会合: meet, join, assemble, hold a meeting

10.接: connect, receive, meet, take over, join, extend

11.会: can, be able to, see, meet, be sure, be likely to

Carefully study all the words on the list, and you will find 3.会面 4.见面 and 8.碰面 are the better choices.

Now substitute "見" in "有一天我們會見" with the three better choices and you will get:

"**有一天我們會会面**"

"**有一天我們會见面**"

"**有一天我們會碰面**"

All three sentences above are acceptable.

You can also input "Some day we will meet" or "Some day we will meet again" in Google Translate

*The result for "Some day we will meet again" is "有一天我们会再见面" is 100% acceptable.

> 一旦我们相遇

The result in Google Translate for this phrase is "Once we meet" And it is correct, which mean your guess was wrong

"一旦(once) 我们(we) 相遇(meet)" is not "有一天(one day) 我們(we)會(will)见面(meet)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not expect such a detailed answer.)) It's just quite difficult to find "the better choices" when a language is not your native language. Probably I need more practice.))

Comment: The obvious choices are the ones that have fewer other meanings.

Answer (score 4):

i think 后会有期 is better.
分别时说的，意思是，以后我们会见面的。

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me sublimate this phrase meaning.To show the beauty of Chinese.

If translate it to Chinese just like that simple,"有一天我們會见面" it's not funny and meaningful.Sounds like “The Soulless Tribute” or “The Walking Dead”

Let's imagine，someone you loved,by some reason could not meet anymore.At the last met time. She/He said "No sorrow is worse than the one after parting.but ***One day we will meet***!"

By Context Match. In Chinese, i will tell you these words "**孔雀东南飞**"。Then,you will find a romantic true story , and open a high leavel language use way. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the answer from @tang ho

> 有一天我們會见面

is not wrong, but usually we don't speak as such.

Bare in mind, when learning foreign language, don't neglect the actual context of your own language. As in English, "Some day we will meet" means "Let's meet up when opportunity deem fit".

Normally, this is the formal way to say such :

> 有机会的话，大家见个面

Nevertheless, there is similar shortened speaking, Chinese use the word 改天/有空/得闲/下次 for "someday".

> 有空的时候见个面 （Mandarin)
>
> 得空见个面 (Mandarin)
>
> 得闲见个面（Cantonese)
>
> 下次见个面 (Mandarin/Cantonese)